# postgresql error when attempting to do a select all from table

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to do the postgresql equivalent of mysql `select * from table` on a postgresql specific database. I can find the name of the table I need within that database when I do:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public';
```

But when I try a select all on the table, I get:

```
SELECT * from Sample;
SELECT * from Sample;
ERROR:  relation "sample" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * from Sample;
                      ^
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the `sample` table?

Comment: Try `SELECT * from "Sample";`

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgresql is case sensitive.

I usually use all lower char for field, tables and functions.
Anyway, you can double quote them.

To full answer your question and see why and when useing quote, i suggest to read this specific section:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: "*Postgresql is case sensitive*" - only for quoted identifiers. For unquoted identifiers, it is **not** case sensitive (as defined by the SQL standard) `Foo`, `foo` and `FOO` all reference the same table, but `"Foo"` and `"FOO"` do **not** reference the same table.

Answer (score 1):

The manes of the tables are stored in `information_schema.tables` so you have to see your table by using `select * from information_schema.tables`. IF your table_schema is "public"
try for a table select `select * from public.sample`, is your table_schema a differed schema chance it to the right one.

this link will help you [Psotgresql doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html)

Answer (score 0):

I tried single-quoting `'Sample'` and it didn't work. Fixed by double-quoting `"Sample"`.

Comment: `'Sample'` is a character literal, not an identifier. Which is documented in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS